# need regexp to extract the string from end of the file path

Tags: regex, tcl, itcl

I have this file path called :

images/Linux/RHEL7-x64/PTSVPL/ptsvpl-esxi-x86_64-7.20.0302.vmdk

and i want to extract the string from the end from this  i.e i want the string :
ptsvpl-esxi-x86_64-7.20.0302.vmdk
 from whole line, please help me for the same.

every time the path vairies and sub folders extends so taught to fetch only the string from last and which has '/' in it after my intented string

Answer (score 2):

There is a command for this:

```
% file tail images/Linux/RHEL7-x64/PTSVPL/ptsvpl-esxi-x86_64-7.20.0302.vmdk
ptsvpl-esxi-x86_64-7.20.0302.vmdk
```

Documentation:
[file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm)

Comment: You *can* use a regular expression if you want, but using `file tail` is clearer and almost twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[^\/]*$
```

This will match all characters except slashes coming after a slash or the beginning of your string in case there are no slashes.

Comment: Actually, `[^/]*$` is sufficient: you don't need a capture group.

Comment: The slash isn't a special character in Tcl REs, so you don't need to escape it. And even if it were, it wouldn't be special inside a bracket expression.

Comment: thanks that regexp worked [^/]*$ and with this i got the output as :
ptsvpl-esxi-x86_64-7.20.0302.vmdk

next is can i get any regexp which will filter only 7.20.0302 from the whole string?

basically extract ptsvpl-esxi-x86_64-{7.20.0302}.vmdk which is flower bracketted and get that as output

Comment: @vinay: try `lindex [split [file rootname [file tail $path]] -] end` with your path stored in the variable `$path`.